# Append jQuery var from outside the function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, var

I have a jQuery function that is run from a Wordpress parent, admin-theme. It looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    var DIV_SIZE = [
        ['1/4','element1-4',1/4,['Column','Gallery','Content','Page']],
        ['1/3','element1-4',1/4,['Column','Gallery','Content','Page']],
    ];
}
```

I need to add an additional value: `,'blog'` like so but do it from the functions.php file in my child theme:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    var DIV_SIZE = [
        ['1/4','element1-4',1/4,['Column','Gallery','Content','Page','blog']],
        ['1/4','element1-4',1/4,['Column','Gallery','Content','Page','blog']],
    ];
}
```

How can I append DIV_SIZE?

Comment: Sorry but i'm a bit confused by your question. You want to add 'blog' to DIV_SIZE from a php script? Cannot you set it first using javascript? Is 'blog' dependant of any server request?

Comment: I don't know jQuery...I have a .js file inside a parent wordpress theme. I need to add an additional option but from a file inside my child theme. It can be a.js or within a php file. Basically I need to add the additional option ,'blog'

Answer (score 0):

This js snippet will add 'blog' entry to each DIV_SIZE embeded array:

```
for (var i = 0, z = DIV_SIZE.length; i < z; i++) {      
    DIV_SIZE[i][3].push('blog');
}
```

But still i don't understand why you don't just add it if its a static value directly when assigning DIV_SIZE variable.

Comment: I can't edit the file that holds the DIV_SIZE. It's located in a wordpress parent theme and I need to merge the 'blog' value with by way of the child theme so the core theme files are unchanged.